# No operation in Scheme Language

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, conditional-statements

I am  having some trouble in how to define no operation in scheme language

like ; in c

i want to do something like this:

```
   (cond
   [(null? exp)  nop ]
    .....
   )
```

if i leave it empty it wiil return #t
thanks!

Comment: Every expression must return a value. If you want a no-op, use the `void` type[1]. To return a void value, use `(void)`. [1]: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._void~3f%29%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheme has no statements, only *expressions*. Each expression returns a value -or may never return-

So you want an expression which does not compute much. You could use *nil* (or `#f`, or any other value) for that purpose:

```
 (cond
   ((null? exp)  ())
  ....
 )
```

If you wrote a condition with only a test - and no "then" body sub-expressions

```
 (cond
   ((null? exp))
 )
```

then the result of the `cond` when `exp` is nil is the result of the `(null? exp)` test which is `#t`
actually, when `exp` is null, you could just return `exp` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Note that functional programs are different to imperative programs. You should always think in every expression/function to return something (the result or value of that expression). With conditionals, you have to be careful to maintain this "something" through all the different branches, as your expression has to yield a value in any case.

Then, you have to decide what you want to return in that case, and build the code accordingly. If you don't want to return `#t`, you can return just `#f` or the empty list:

```
(cond
  [(null? exp) #f]
  .....
  )
```

In fact, if you think carefuly, the concept of a "no op" (that is, do nothing), in C, is almost the same than "producing some value", because you're doing nothing apart from producing the value, that doesn't induce any change at all in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your program to eliminate useless condition. But if you just need a nil value, the standard answer is to say `(if #f #f)`, which is a one-legged if that is always false but has no false expression, hence returns nothing.

Comment: For what it seems in the OP usage of square brackets, he or she is using Racket. This is not permited in Racket, because precisely it yields no value.

Comment: The question is tagged Scheme, not Racket. And most Scheme systems accept square brackets, not just Racket, so I don't think we can assume Racket. For instance, I tested in Chez Scheme, and it works fine. I know that Racket is no longer Scheme, but didn't know that this would fail in Racket. I still think the best answer is to rewrite the cond expression to eliminate the useless clause.

Comment: @user448810 you are correct, i did needed to re arrange my conditions in order for the program to work, and i also used Basile Starynkevitch solution. so thanks you guys!